# Smooth-Div-Scroll and iPad

Tags: smooth-scrolling

Has anyone had any success with Smooth-Div-Scroll and the iPad ?

My site doesn't seem to scroll.

http://paulcostello.net/html/main.html

Answer (score 2):

Smooth Div Scroll is not prepared with eventhandlers for handling touch events (iPad, iPhone, Android devices etc). When I run the demo pages on my iPhone pages with Smooth Div Scroll won't break and scrollers will autoscroll, but user interaction doesn't work well.

There are plans for integrating touch events but since it's a very different way of interacting (tapping, dragging and swiping) it would take some time to get it right. For example, the hotspots trigger on mouseover - there's no such thing as mouseover on a touch device.

**Edit several days later:**

I have done some experimenting and it's not too difficult to add basic touch support. With this I mean a scroller that moves when you drag your finger over it and it moves the same amount of pixels as your finger moves on screen. It basically follows your finger. :-) I have this working in a rather messy developer version.

The tricky part is adding some flare to it like swiping and deceleration. On iPad or iPhone for example you can swipe a webpage and the faster you swipe it, the faster/further it will scroll. After your finger has left the screen the deceleration kicks in and it seems to follow some sort of curve.

Another tricky part is compatibility. I have only tried it on iPhone so far. I don't know if this will be an issue or not until I have had the opportunity to try it on other units (iPad, Android phone) etc.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I love SmoothDivScroll, I'd eat it on toast if I could.

Comment: It's a little spam, but I don't know how to contact You faster, tkahn. Could You please check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10140662/jquery-smooth-div-scroll-event-handler ?

Comment: Hi! Didn't find your question (removed by author) so I guess things worked out without my help?

Comment: Hi Thomas, any news on Smooth Div Scroll working on iPad? Even some basic functionality just to make it enough functional? Thanks

Comment: Now there's a lightweight plugin especially written for touch, http://smoothtouchscroll.com/.

Answer (score 0):

what about touch gestures in Smooth Div Scroll? Do you know http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/?

I'm very interested in it, and I can donate for that feature. In fact I've donated using flattr (user studioweb)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now [Smooth Div Scroll](http://www.smoothdivscroll.com) has support for touch scrolling!

Answer (score 0):

I has been succeded to swipe on Ipad using smooth div scroll.
Currently realeased the jquery smoothDivScroll version 1.3. This version use kinetic js

please see this link to display more details
[smooth div in touch](http://smoothdivscroll.com/options.html#touchScrolling)

Comment: Can you include the relevant detail in your answer? Answers are supposed to be stand alone so that in the event a link stops working, the answer remains useful to others.